# Function returning simple hashcode in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, parameter-passing, return-value, hashcode

I'm trying to handle following programming exercise from my C++ book: "**Write a function which takes a string as argument and returns a primitve hash-code, which is calculated by adding the values of all characters in the string.**"

My solution to this is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define clrscr() system("cls")
#define pause() system("pause")

using namespace std;

int hashc(char string[]);

int main()
{
    char phrase[256];

    cout << "This program converts any string into primitve hash-code." << "\n";
    cout << "Input phrase: ";   cin.getline(phrase, sizeof(phrase));
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Hash-code for your phrase is: " << hashc(phrase) << "\n\n";

    pause();
    return(0);
}

int hashc(char string[])
{
    int index;
    int length;
    int hash_value = 0;

    length = strlen(string);

    for(index = 0; index >= length; ++index)
    {
        hash_value = hash_value + string[index];
    }


    return(hash_value);
}
```

The problem is: the function always returns `hash_value = 0` as it seems that it is skipping the for-loop. When I return `length` in the function it gives back the correct length of a given string (which is `index >= length` for `index = 0`). Therefore it should normally trigger the for-loop, shouldn't it? A little hint right here is greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: What about using the appropriate specializations for [std::hash](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/hash)??

Comment: Yeah, this would probably be the normal way to go about this. I'm at chapter 9 of my C++ fundamentals book which is about passing arguments and returning values. I think the point is to solve those tasks with the stuff i've learned so far.

Comment: In `for (a;b;c)`, the expression `b` needs to be `true` for a loop iteration to be performed, it should yield `false` to terminate the loop. It seems you got that backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idiomatic for-loop should look like this:

```
for(index = 0; index < length; ++index)
{
    hash_value += string[index];
}
```

The key features are that the index starts at 0 (`index = 0`), the index is compared to the length with 'less-than' (`index < length`) and, as you have it, the index is incremented using pre-increment (`++index`).

Comment: Damn, i cant believe I've spend the last hour to get the hang of that... of course... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
for(index = 0; index < length; ++index)
```

You're never entering the loop at the moment, and no characters caused a segmentation fault on my system. It enters the loop in the only situation that it passes the condition (`length >= index`, i.e. 0 >= 0) and then loops until it attempts to access an illegal location, at which point the seg fault occurs.

Comment: Can you improve your explanation of the seg fault?

Comment: ugh... C strings are expected to be 0-terminated. So accessing the 0th character of an empty string is fine... not sure what you mean by that segfault.

Comment: If the reason for the seg fault is wrong then I'm content to remove it, but it definitely caused a seg fault when I built and ran the example.

Comment: Corrected. I was puzzled about the `\0` causing a seg fault, which after thinking about it (and modifying my version) obviously wasn't the case. Thanks for the steer.